# jQuery video endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Okay so, basically my code is about playing a video in HTML5 video tag (let's name it the intro), so at the end of the intro, the video stops and there are two invisible divs acting as buttons, each div is clickable, and when clicked, it should just change the source of the video with some animation. Everything works fine blah blah, until the second video plays out, and then slightly changes back its source to the first video (intro), the intro plays out, but instead of stopping like it should, at the end the video starts repeating itself endlessly. Here's the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var vid1 = "media/Dance001.mp4";
var vid2 = "media/Dance001.mp4";
var vidsrc;
var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();
$.keyframe.debug = true;
    $.keyframe.define({
    name: 'blackout',
    '0%': {'background-color: transparent': 'transparent'},
    '50%': {'background-color': 'black'},
    '100%': {'background-color': 'transparent'}
});

function blackOut() {
    $("#blackout1").css("display", "initial");
    $("#blackout1").playKeyframe({
    name: 'blackout', // name of the keyframe you want to bind to the selected element
    duration: '2s', // [optional, default: 0, in ms] how long you want it to last in milliseconds
    timingFunction: 'linear', // [optional, default: ease] specifies the speed curve of the animation
    delay: '0s', //[optional, default: 0s]  how long you want to wait before the animation starts
    iterationCount: '1', //[optional, default:1]  how many times you want the animation to repeat
    direction: 'normal', //[optional, default: 'normal']  which direction you want the frames to flow
    fillMode: 'forwards', //[optional, default: 'forward']  how to apply the styles outside the animation time, default value is forwards
    complete: function(){$("#blackout1").css("display", "none");} //[optional] Function fired after the animation is complete. If repeat is infinite, the function will be fired every time the animation is restarted.
});
}
function changeVideo(path){
    vidsrc = path;
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#myVideo").attr("src", path);
    $("#left-click").css("display", "none");
    $("#right-click").css("display", "none");
    },1000)
    }
    
function changetoIntro(){
        if(vidsrc == vid1 || vidsrc == vid2) {
    $("#myVideo").on('ended',function(){
        blackOut();
        setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myVideo").attr("src", "media/Intro.mp4");
        $("#left-click").css("display", "initial");
        $("#right-click").css("display", "initial");},1000);
        vidsrc = ""; }); 
    } 
    else {} 
    }
    
$("#left-click").click(function () {
    blackOut();
    changeVideo("media/Dance001.mp4");
    changetoIntro();
    });

$("#right-click").click(function () {
    blackOut();
    changeVideo("media/Dance002.mp4");
    changetoIntro();
    });
        
});
```

```html
<body>

<div class = "container">
    <div id = "video-container" class = "video-container">
        <video id = "myVideo" class = "myVideo" width="800" height="850" autoplay>
            <source src="media/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <div id = "left-click" style="cursor: pointer"></div>
        <div id = "right-click" style="cursor: pointer"></div>
        <div id = "blackout1" class = "blackout1"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src='scripts/jquery.keyframes.min.js'></script>
<script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: you probably need to cancel the setInterval/onEnded so if doesn't keep firing

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I've changed my jQuery code a bit, the setInterval function is no longer present, yet, outcome is the same